# Laravel, how to call or append(join) another model with condition in existing model condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am stuck with search functionality from two different tables (`VenueHall` and `Venue`). The data is coming in the `search1 parameter. I am able to search the data from one table (`VenueHall`) but I am not able to map with another table (`Venue`) using the existing object from the first table (`$VenueHall`).

```
$VenueHall = VenueHall::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
$VenueHall = $VenueHall->with('venue');
$VenueHall = $VenueHall->with('venueType');
$VenueHall = $VenueHall->with('venue.area');

if (Input::has('query') && $searchQuery = Input::get('query'))
{
    $perecentilify = '%'. $searchQuery .'%';

    $VenueHall = $VenueHall->where(function($query) use ($perecentilify, $searchQuery) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $perecentilify)
            ->orWhere('code', 'LIKE', $perecentilify);
            //->orWhere('from venue table');
        });                 
    }

    $data = array(
        'venueHall' => $VenueHall->paginate(2)
    );

    return View::make('venues/venues', array('data' => $data));
```

I am not able to map the `//->orWhere('from venue table')` clause which comes from the `Venue` table. Please help me out get the data from the two tables based on the search value in the search box.

Comment: What are the foreign keys between `Venue` and `VenueHall`?

Answer (score 0):

Often I find joins to be the easiest solution in such cases:

```
$VenueHall = VenueHall
    ::join('Venue', 'Venue.id', '=', 'VenueHall.venue_id')
    ->where('VenueHall.name', 'LIKE', $perecentilify)
    ->orWhere('VenueHall.code', 'LIKE', $perecentilify)
    ->orWhere('Venue.name', 'LIKE', $perecentilify)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->with(['venue', 'venueType', 'venue.area'])
    ->paginate(2)
;
```